# How to change the style of listbox in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have  created one textbox named cb and i added items

```
cb.addItem( { label: "Sovereign", data:1 } );
cb.addItem( { label: "Banks (with option - I)", data:2 } );
cb.addItem( { label: "Banks (with option - II)", data:3 } );
cb.addItem( { label: "Retail", data:4 } );
cb.addItem( { label: "Residential", data:5 } );
cb.addItem( { label: "Corporate", data:6 } );
```

i want to style these list items above.i have put the setStyle to text box but its changing only the stlye of selected item.

```
var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("verdana",12,0x000000);
cb.textField.setStyle ("textFormat",myFormat);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to format the cell renderer also, hopefully this post will help:

[Combo box text formatting](http://www.rockabit.com/2008/04/15/combobox-text-formatting-in-as3/)